# How to pass multiple kwargs parameter to Django Class Based View (ListView) at HTML page?

Tags: django

```
Views.py

class CalendarWeekView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    login_url = 'signup'
    model = Event
    template_name = 'calendar.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        d = get_date(self.request.GET.get('month', None)) 

        w = int(self.request.GET.get('week', None))

        cal = Calendar(d.year, d.month, w)
        html_cal = cal.formatmonth(withyear=True)
        context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
        context['prev_month'] = prev_month(d)
        context['next_month'] = next_month(d)
        context['current_month'] = current_month(d)
        context['next_week'] = next_week(w)
       
        return context


urls.py

app_name = 'calendarapp'
urlpatterns = [

path('week/', views.CalendarWeekView.as_view(), name='calendarWeek'),

]
```

calendar.html

href="{% url 'calendarapp:calendarWeek' %}?{{ next_week}}/?{{ current_month }}"

How to pass multiple kwargs parameter to Django Class Based View (ListView) at HTML page using URL Path at HTML page ?

Comment: `/path/to/page?month=10&week=2`?

Comment: Wonderful, thanks ! The trick is having the "&" in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters in a [*Query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Querystring) are separated by an `&`, so you can call this with:

```
href="{% url 'calendarapp:calendarWeek' %}?week={{ next_week}}&month={{ current_month }}"
```

That being said, for a fixed number of parameters, it is often better to work with [*path parameters* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#example), this is more convenient to use in the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url), and results in cleaner and more elegant URLs.

Comment: Thanks, you really help !